# PayPal Return URL not working while transferring payment to personal account

Tags: php, paypal

It is possible to enable return url for business account editing user website preference, but if I want to transfer money to personal account on paypal, then return url is not working

Please suggest

The HTML code for redirecting to paypal

```
<html>
<head><title>Processing Payment...</title></head>
<div id="loading_image" style="position:absolute; left:600px; top:300px;">
<img src="themes/theme1/images/waiting.gif" /> Redirecting to Paypal.
</div><form method="post" name="paypal_form" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2"/>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"/>
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="email"/>
<input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="http://url/admin/transactions/index/successfull"/>
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://url/admin/transactions/index/failed"/>
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://url/quotes/paypal_ipn"/>
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="3|4|1|3"/>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Payment for Job Completion"/>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="11.4"/>
</form>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no any return url in paypal for success response you have to send success_url variable to paypal to respond back

Comment: It's not working, I have updated my question with html code that I am using to redirect user to paypal

Comment: I dont understand exactly what you want to do please explain.

Comment: I just want to simply redirect user back to website after making payment